# Special symbol with context variable

Tags: html, django, templates

In my django template I have:

```
<strong>Copyright &copy; </strong> {{ copyright }}
```

Where:

```
copyright = "Company &copy; 2014-2018"
```

Which shows:

```
Copyright © Company &copy; 2014-2018
```

Why is the first symbol ok, and the second not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django template [escapes variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping), so `&copy`; becomes `&amp;copy` in the rendered template, which displays as `&copy;` in your browser.

You can prevent the escaping by avoid this by using [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) in your view,

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
copyright = mark_safe("Company &copy; 2014-2018")
```

Or by using the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter in the template.

```
{{ copyright|safe }}
```

Note that it is only safe to mark this string as safe because you control the value. You should always escape input from users, otherwise you are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Django autoescapes html in tags by default. If you want to include html use

```
 {{copyright|safe}}
```